# VS2013: How do I get it to grab focus at a breakpoint?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

As I recall, VS2008 and VS2010 used to grab focus automatically when a breakpoint was hit.

VS2013 doesn't seem to do this by default. Is there a way to enable this behaviour?

I've lost count of the time I've wasted by reaching a breakpoint in a web application, hitting F5, realising that VS doesn't have focus, clicking continue and having the page refresh back to the top level, losing the last several minutes of test data entry!

Comment: On my machine VS 2013 does grab focus on a breakpoint hit by default.